# Current loggedin User name is displayed on aspx webpage when I enable windows authentication in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I'm creating a web page (aspx) to get the current loggedin user information when a user tries to access the page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userName = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
}
```

so I'm getting userName here correctly (domain\username), but the problem i'm facing is that, this userName is getting displayed on the webpage also on top of the form. Which i do not want. 
I'm not using any of Response.Write or Console.Write to display it on the webpage.

i think i'm missing some configuration in web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <pages>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
    </namespaces>
    <controls>
      <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Wherever 'userName ' is referenced on the `.aspx page`, it will get displayed. Provide details about `.aspx page` so that I can look more.

Comment: "the problem i'm facing is that, this userName is getting displayed on the webpage also on top of the form." Show a screenshot please. Also you need to share a minimal project to reproduce the issue if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ah what a stupid mistake. 
in aspx file, earlier I had added the code <%=User.Identity.Name%> in the beginning of file. Once I removed it worked as I wanted.

Thanks.